# Sorting of set of objects is incorrect

Tags: c++, c++11, object, set, overloading

When I print the whole set, the result is unsorted AND it contains one duplicate.
The object `Person` has a surname, a familyname and year of birth (all 3 are strings). I first sort by year of birth, then by familyname and then by surname. Per se, there are no identical persons (but even if was the case, it should be eliminated as they get inserted into the `set` ).

To be more concrete, I create a set of persons like this:

```
std::set <Person> greatUncles;
```

and insert them like this:

```
greatUncles.insert(Person("bla", "bla", "1900"));
```

Here's are the essential things from class `Person`:

```
class Person {
public:
  //...

  Person(std::string s, std::string f, std::string y)
    :surname(s), familyname(f), yearOfBirth(y)
  {
  }

  //...

  std::string getSurname() const {
    return surname;
  }

  std::string getFamilyname() const {
    return familyname;
  }

  std::string getYearOfBirth() const {
    return yearOfBirth;
  }

private:
  std::string surname;
  std::string familyname;
  std::string yearOfBirth;
};

//to print the set, overload the '<<' operator
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Person &person) {
  o << person.getSurname() << " "
    << person.getFamilyname() << " "
    << person.getYearOfBirth() << std::endl;
  return o;
}

//to order the set, overload the '<' operator
bool operator< (Person const &p1, Person const &p2) {
  int compareYearOfBirth = p1.getYearOfBirth().compare(p2.getYearOfBirth());

  if (compareYearOfBirth == 0) {
    int compareFamilyname = p1.getFamilyname().compare(p2.getFamilyname());
    if (compareFamilyname == 0) {
      return p1.getSurname().compare(p2.getSurname());
    } else
      return compareFamilyname;
  } else
    return compareYearOfBirth;
}
```

and here is how I print the set of great-uncles:

```
void printGreatUncles(std::set <Person> &greatUncles) {
    std::ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("greatuncle.dat");

    if (outputFile.is_open()) {
      for(Person const & person:greatUncles) {
        outputFile << person;
      }
      outputFile.close();
    }
  }
```

Now the output in a certain case should look like this (sorted by year):

```
Sebastian Furtweger 1942
Nikolaus Furtweger 1951
Archibald Furtweger 1967
```

but it looks like this:

```
Archibald Furtweger 1967
Sebastian Furtweger 1942
Nikolaus Furtweger 1951
Archibald Furtweger 1967
```

I can't figure it for my life what (things) I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please don't put `...` in your code snippet, or put them in comments, it makes your code impossible to copy/paste/run directly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll remember it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::set` requires the comparator provides a strict weak ordering.  Part of that is if `a < b == true` then `b < a == false` but you don't have this.  Lets imagine the birth year and the family names are the same, and only the surnames are different.  In you example you would return some positive or negative number which is converted to `true` since only `0` is `false`.  If you run the check backwards then you get the opposite value in the integer, but it still results in `true`.

To fix this C++11 offers `std::tie` that you can use to build a `std::tuple` of the members and its `operator <` is built to do the right thing.  That makes you code look like

```
bool operator< (Person const &p1, Person const &p2) {
  return std::tie(p1.getYearOfBirth(), p1.getFamilyname(), p1.getSurname()) < 
         std::tie(p2.getYearOfBirth(), p2.getFamilyname(), p2.getSurname());
}
```

---

If you ever want to do this going forward and can use C++20 then you can add to Person

```
auto operator<=>(const Person&) const = default;
```

and that will automatically give you operators ==, !=, <, <=, >, and >= for `Person` and they will "do the right thing" as long as you want all members compared in the order they are defined in the class.

Comment: I would consider this the idiomatic solution. +1

Comment: @JesperJuhl At least for now.  C++20 lets use do `auto operator<=>(const class_name&) const = default;`

Comment: Sure, but that's still an unreleased standard. What you posted is the idiomatic solution for C++17 and lower. :)

Comment: Writing a method `as_tuple` might avoid to repeat members for `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: @Jarod42 would it be better to name it `as_tie()`, given that tie creates a tuple of references, rather than `to_tuple()` to make a tuple-like copy? I ask because it is not something I have had reason to do at all.

Comment: @GemTaylor: I like `as_tie` :-).

Answer (score 4):

You are returning the `int` returned by `std::string::compare` as a `bool`. That's not what you want, as both `1` and `-1` are converted to `true`.

The correct comparison code would be:

```
//to order the set, overload the '<' operator
bool operator< (Person const &p1, Person const &p2) {
  int compareYearOfBirth = p1.getYearOfBirth().compare(p2.getYearOfBirth());

  if (compareYearOfBirth == 0) {
    int compareFamilyname = p1.getFamilyname().compare(p2.getFamilyname());
    if (compareFamilyname == 0) {
      return p1.getSurname().compare(p2.getSurname()) < 0;
    } else
      return compareFamilyname < 0;
  } else
    return compareYearOfBirth < 0;
}
```

The `std::tie` option by NathanOliver is significantly less error-prone than the above (although you can still easily mess up any copy-pasted stuff - I've done it before).

In C++20 there will be an even simpler solution (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons)):

```
class Person {
  // ...
public:
  auto operator<=>(const Person &) const = default;
}
```

This will basically provide all comparisons exactly as if you manually implemented them via comparisons on all members `std::tie`d together.